# Настройки звука

Tags: c#, unity3d

Всем привет, у меня возникла проблема с настройкой звука. Добавил в настройки Slider который регулирует громкость звука (по крайне мере должен регулировать), но регулирует только звук в главном меню а когда переходишь на игровую сцену то настройки не действуют. Как это можно исправить?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class scrAudio : MonoBehaviour {

private AudioSource audioScr;
private float musicVol = 1f;

void Start()
{
    audioScr = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
}
void Update()
{
    audioScr.volume = musicVol;
}
public void setVol(float Volue)
{
    musicVol = Volue;
}
}
```

Comment: А сам AudioSource на другой сцене (простите за тавтологию) - другой или тот же самый, у которого изменили настройки?

Comment: я решил для начала сделать префаб  из настроек и кинуть на другую сцену (думал что будет связь и будет работать)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У юнити существует такая вещь, как [Audio Mixer](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AudioMixer.html). Он отвечает за то, каким именно образом все звуки будут выводиться для игрока. Всем `AudioSource` можно задавать звуковые каналы внутри миксера и таким образом, прежде чем воспроизвестись, все звуки из источников будут проходить через настройки конкретного канала.

Другими словами: громкость вам нужно будет регулировать только в этом миксере, а какой именно источник, с какой сцены или в какой момент воспроизводит этот звук - значения иметь не будет. При этом вы сможете добавлять различные звуковые эффекты на конкретный звуковой канал.

Вот есть [серия видео-уроков](https://unity3d.com/ru/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/5-pre-order-beta/audiomixer-and-audiomixer-groups) от Unity на эту тему